# How to make eclipse IDE more flexible?

Tags: eclipse, tooltip, keil

I am new on Eclipse from Keil C. I have few tips to make a quick code on Keil but I can't find it on Eclipse. Can anyone help me, please?

1. Outlining

[image]

To Collapse/Expand All Definition like this

[image]

2. Find all in project

To find a string in all project at the moment.
[image]

3. Go to Definition/Reference of a functions or variables

To jump immediately to it.
[image]

4. Text completion (important for me)
   This tip makes me very fast coding. I will set up a keyword delegate with a text, document or any string. Next, I using keystrokes (Ctrl + Shift + Space) to appear completely string.
   Example:
   I type "cm" -> press keystrokes above it transform to /* | */ where | char is a location of the cursor after the text appeared and I continue typing my comment into it.

[image]

I'm very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see all of the Eclipse shortcuts via `Help -> Show Active Keybindings`, or with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. There you can also find some of the answers:

1. Collapse All: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, Expand All: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>
2. Mark desired project in Project Explorer, then call menu `Search -> File` and search with scope to "Enclosing Project"
3. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and do left mouse click on method/variable to go to its definition
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to show Template proposals. You can create new templates via menu `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates`.
   [image: Eclipse menu for adding code templates]

For your example: Click on "New...". Enter "cm" as name, "Enter a new comment" as description and as pattern "/*${cursor}*/" (please find other available variables by clicking on the button "Insert Variable..."). 
[image: Eclipse mask for new code template]

Confirm with "OK" and close Preferences-Window with click on "Apply and Close". That's it! :-)

Comment: Thanks, RoM, in part 4 which any method make a user template?

Comment: Hi Huu, I added additional informations. Hope, it helps.

Comment: Yes, thank for your kind reply, it's very clear. I set up successful :)

Comment: Great, my pleasure! Don't forget to mark my answer as solution! Thnx! :)